# Can we develop a web and mobile application (Android, iOS, web) with single code base by using React Native?

Tags: react-native

Can you please help with this.

I am trying to develop mobile and web apps using react native with single code base for web, android and ios. Can we Develop Web and Mobile Application with single code base by using React Native?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is **yes**. However, there are a lot of caveats that you could encounter along the road with certain device requirements and functionality where you may have to write conditional code, but it could still stay in the same codebase.

The easiest way to get started is by using Expo (https://expo.io), which would let you get started with a project that could be run on Android, iOS, and the Web (via React Native Web) all with very minimal setup on your part.

Comment: If we go with react native for all platforms can i know any performance issues

Comment: by using expo some native libraries will support..?

Comment: can you please post some example any ? that we can develop mobile and web apps using react native

Comment: And Finally, Thanks for you response and support

Comment: I'm happy to answer specific questions, but I think you'd be best served by going to the Expo page and reading their documentation.

Comment: @jnpdx could you update your answer and go more in deep?

Comment: @KaMZaTa the best path is probably to ask a new question that asks specifically about what you need addressed.